# Express - function prototype toString() in error handling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I had a longstanding issue with Express spitting out HTML strings instead of JSON, when we clearly were trying to force JSON to always come out of the server no matter what -

it turns out it was a problem in my error handling middleware - I was missing the next argument, e.g.:

this was failing:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res) {
        res.status(err.status || 500).json({
            error: 'sorry the API experienced an error serving your priority request'
        });
});
```

this was behaving correctly:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500).json({
            error: 'sorry the API experienced an error serving your priority request'
        });
});
```

so as you can see, adding the fourth argument 'next' allowed Express to recognize this as an error handling callback function.

my question is - how does Express know about the fourth argument being in place, or let alone the types of the arguments? My only guess is that Express is using Function.prototype.toString() to look at the number of arguments. Or are they doing it another way?

Comment: [This page](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.error-handling) talks about Error Handling Middleware, and how the functions take four arguments.

Comment: thanks, that page is how I discovered the fix, but I am wondering why and how Express implements this

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.  It probably uses the [Function.prototype.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) property, which returns the number of arguments expected by the function.

Comment: It does use the `length` property, you can see the test [here](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/router/layer.js#L65).

Comment: yeah, that could be, and frankly I find it pretty lame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written in the comments it uses [`Function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)

> `length` is a property of a function object, and indicates how many
>   arguments the function expects, i.e. the number of formal parameters.

and below is the [code fragment from express repository](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/layer.js#L65):

```
Layer.prototype.handle_error = function handle_error(error, req, res, next) {
  var fn = this.handle;

  if (fn.length !== 4) {
    // not a standard error handler
    return next(error);
  }

  try {
    fn(error, req, res, next);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```